# Separate merged points on image using python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a script to count dots on an image (very original) using Python and OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Image read
img = cv2.imread("img.tif", 0)

# Denoising
denoisedImg = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img);

# Threshold (binary image)
# thresh – threshold value.
# maxval – maximum value to use with the THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types.
# type – thresholding type
th, threshedImg = cv2.threshold(denoisedImg, 100, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU) # src, thresh, maxval, type

# Perform morphological transformations using an erosion and dilation as basic operations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,8))
morphImg = cv2.morphologyEx(threshedImg, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Find and draw contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(morphImg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contoursImg = cv2.cvtColor(morphImg, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(contoursImg, contours, -1, (255,100,0), 3)

cv2.imwrite("image.tif", contoursImg)

print("Dots number: {}".format(len(contours)))
```

On the left image, the result I achieved using the code above. On the right image, what I want to achieve.

[image: 1]
As you can see, I'm looking for a way to split dots which are a little connected into two separate dots and I was wondering if there was a "magical" function allowing me to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the image on the left your original input image? Instead of using `cv2.MORPH_RECT` when creating the kernel, use `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE`. Also use `cv2.MORPH_OPEN` to erode (separate the dots)

Comment: My image on the left is the result of the script. Ok I'm going to try that. Thanks :)